# Python: How to use the dict.get() function?

Tags: python, python-3.x, beautifulsoup

I'm a python beginner and im quiet stuck in a exercise.
i'm using beautiful soup for parsing web pages.
i have to update my link with the index position that i got `u = tags[s]`. i know that i must use a .get() that reads the variable that stores the html line which is (url).
When i try to use `url1 = u.get(url)` and print. my result is None.
So how i can use the .get() proporly?

```
import urllib.request, urllib.parse, urllib.error
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import ssl
# Ignore SSL certificate errors
ctx = ssl.create_default_context()
ctx.check_hostname = False
ctx.verify_mode = ssl.CERT_NONE

url = input('Enter - ')
s = input("Enter position: ")
m = input("Enter count: ")

s = int(s)
m = int(m)
while m > 0:
    html = urllib.request.urlopen(url).read()
    soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')
    tags = soup("a")
    m = m - 1
    #print(tags)
    u = tags[s]
    url1 = u.get(url)
    print(url1)
```

Comment: Print u and check if it contains the key as `url` or not. `None` is received from the dict if the key is not found.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at the [Python docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#dict.get) for the `dict` type.

Regarding the `.get()` function it states (bold mine):

> get(key[, default]) Return the value for key if key is in the
> dictionary, else default. **If default is not given, it defaults to
> None**, so that this method never raises a KeyError.

Example:

```
# Create a dict.
d = {'name': 'bob'}

# Index to the (non-existent) 'age' key.
d.get('age')
>>> None   # Not actually printed to the console. Added for demonstration.

# Index to the 'name' key.
d.get('name')
>>> 'bob'

# Index to the (non-existent) 'age' key, using a default value.
d.get('age', 'unknown')
>>> 'unknown'
```

Answer:

To answer your question, if `None` is returned from the `.get()` call, then the key being indexed does not exist.  If a default value should be returned (to keep following code from falling over), pass a value into the optional `default` parameter.

Comment: all i had to do is to url = u.get("href",None)

Comment: Excellent, glad it’s helped you.  Would you mind clicking the tick (check mark) by the answer to shows it’s been accepted.   (Standard SO practice). Cheers mate.

Comment: thanks so much i clicked the tick. really it's so frustrating going in this path but also so rewarding at the same time.